# Replace a substring at a particular position in a string in Java

Tags: java, string, substring

Following is my string variable :

```
String str = "Home(om), Home(gia)";
```

I want to replace the substring `om` present between `()` with `tom`.

I am able to find the index of `()` in which `om` is present, but the following will not work :

```
int i1 = str.indexOf("(");
int i2 = str.indexOf(")");

str = str.replace(str.substring(i1+1,i2),"tom");
```

I require the result as `Home(tom), Home(gia)`.

How to do this?

Comment: whar is expected output ?

Comment: What are other potential inputs/outputs? It's unclear what exactly you want this code to do given a different `str`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would not use any `replace()` method if you know the indexes of the substring you want to replace.  The problem is that this statement:

```
str = str.replace(str.substring(someIndex, someOtherIndex), replacement);
```

first computes the substring, and then replaces *all* occurrences of that substring in the original string.  `replace` doesn't know or care about the original indexes.

It's better to just break up the string using `substring()`:

```
int i1 = str.indexOf("(");
int i2 = str.indexOf(")");

str = str.substring(0, i1+1) + "tom" + str.substring(i2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex with `replaceAll`

```
String str = "Home(om)";

str = str.replaceAll("[(].*[)]", "(tom)");
System.out.println(str);
```

Output:

> Home(tom)

`[(]`  : look for `(`

`.*` : capture all except line break mean `\n\r`

`[)]`  : look for `)`

**UPDATE :**

You can use `replaceFirst` with non-greedy quantifier `?`

```
    String str = "Home(om), Home(gia)";

    str = str.replaceFirst("([(](.*?)[)])", "(tom)");
    System.out.println(str);
```

**Output:**

> Home(tom), Home(gia)

Comment: But this will not work in case of `String str = "Home(om), Home(gia)";`. It will give me the result `Home(tom), Home(tom)`. I need `Home(tom), Home(gia)`

Comment: @seno71625 i agree but i thought you said `I require the result in the form of Home(tom).` any way let me try

Comment: @seno71625 Your question is a bit unclear... If you "require `"Home(tom), Home(gia)"`", I can do that: `return "Home(tom), Home(gia)";`